# Amadeus Point of Interest Search INVALID_DATA_RECEIVED

Tags: amadeus

Using the Amadeus Node SDK, Amadeus [Points of Interest API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/destination-content/api-doc/points-of-interest/api-reference) only works for some geographical coordinates.

I am currently looking at some Points of Interest in France and everything north of Paris does not seem to work, and Amadeus responds with the error `INVALID DATA RECEIVED`.

Example of coordinates that work (Orleans, France):

**Latitude**: 47.90082
**Longitude**: 1.90283

Example of coordinates that don't work (Rouen, France):

**Latitude**: 49.443231
**Longitude**: 1.0999

Example error response:

```
{"response":{"contentType":"application/vnd.amadeus+json","statusCode":400,"request":{"host":"api.amadeus.com","port":443,"ssl":true,"scheme":"https","verb":"GET","path":"/v1/reference-data/locations/pois","params":{"latitude":49.443231,"longitude":1.0999,"radius":20},"queryPath":"/v1/reference-data/locations/pois?latitude=49.443231&longitude=1.0999&radius=20","bearerToken":"TOKEN","clientVersion":"4.0.0","languageVersion":"12.2.0","appId":null,"appVersion":null,"headers":{"User-Agent":"amadeus-node/4.0.0 node/12.2.0","Accept":"application/json, application/vnd.amadeus+json","Authorization":"Bearer TOKEN","Content-Type":"application/vnd.amadeus+json"}},"body":"{"errors":[{"status":400,"code":4926,"title":"INVALID DATA RECEIVED","detail":"","source":{"parameters":["longitude"]}}]}","result":{"errors":[{"status":400,"code":4926,"title":"INVALID DATA RECEIVED","detail":"","source":{"parameters":["longitude"]}}]},"parsed":true},"description":[{"status":400,"code":4926,"title":"INVALID DATA RECEIVED","detail":"","source":{"parameters":["longitude"]}}],"code":"ClientError"}"}
```

```
var Amadeus = require('amadeus');

var amadeus = new Amadeus({
  clientId: 'PRODUCTION_ID',
  clientSecret: 'PRODUCTION_SECRET',
  hostname: 'production'
});

exports.autocompleteCreate = async (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body);
    // I'm getting lat/lng from a POST request
    var latitude = parseFloat(JSON.stringify(req.body.latitude).toString().substring(0,9));
    var longitude = parseFloat(JSON.stringify(req.body.longitude).toString().substring(0,6));

    amadeus.referenceData.locations.pointsOfInterest.get({
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        radius: 20
    }).then(
        function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was linked to the computation of the radius (for specific places). It has been fixed and delivered. You shouldn't face the problem anymore.

Comment: I am using the production environment. I thus get results for any city in France that is south of Paris, but anything north does not work. Have you tried querying POIs with the lat/long I gave for Rouen?

Comment: I did: GET `https://api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/pois?latitude=49.443231&longitude=1.0999` and it works fine for me. Are you sure. you are using the production environment? Can you share your code how you initialize the SDK and how you call the API?

Comment: Ok I reproduce your issue, it seems that adding a radius of 20 is the issue. Let me ask the development and come back to you

Comment: Thank you! Added a sample code in my original post just in case. Note: for the longitude, I've tried with different numbers of decimals to see if that could have been the issue, but none work for some cities.

Comment: I updated the response. The issue has been fixed. Thank you very much for raising this! Let us know if you face any other problems.

Comment: Thanks, for the quick response, Anthony. I'll make more tests today and keep you posted in case I stumble on other issues..

Comment: Still not fixed, I tried searching in Moscow and received the same error, req: `https://api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/pois?latitude=55.751849391735284&longitude=37.62542724609376&radius=15&categories=SIGHTS`, res: `{"errors":[{"status":400,"code":4926,"title":"INVALID DATA RECEIVED","detail":"","source":{"parameters":["longitude"]}}]}`

Comment: I have been doing some tests and this specific request works with values of radius lower than 12. We are internally reviewing the issue. Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: @dnc123 the issue has been fixed. Thanks for reporting this.