# INVALID_DATA_RECEIVED for Amadeus Point of Interest Search specifically for Helsinki with radius greater than 12

Tags: amadeus

Similar issue to [Amadeus Point of Interest Search INVALID_DATA_RECEIVED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61907488/amadeus-point-of-interest-search-invalid-data-received/61908330#61908330)

Increasing the radius parameter beyond `12` of a get request to the Point of Interest Search endpoint raises a 400 error where the longitude error is stated to be the problem.

This occurs in the production environment and specifically for `latitude=60.16952` and `longitude=24.93545` which is somewhere in Helsinki.

This request, as well as requests using other latitudes and longitudes work as expected.

```
https://api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/pois?latitude=37.566&longitude=126.9784&radius=20&page%5Blimit%5D=100&categories=SHOPPING
```

The following call works as expected and I receive a list of POIs:

```
https://api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/pois?latitude=60.16952&longitude=24.93545&radius=12&page%5Blimit%5D=100&categories=SHOPPING
```

But when repeating the previous call with a radius greater than 12, such as in the following call:

```
https://api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/pois?latitude=60.16952&longitude=24.93545&radius=13&page%5Blimit%5D=100&categories=SHOPPING
```

I receive

```
{"errors":[{"status":400,"code":4926,"title":"INVALID DATA RECEIVED","detail":"","source":{"parameters":["longitude"]}}]}
```